# JQuery/Javascript and the use of && operators

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I'm trying to get a simple conditional statement to work, and running into problems.  The failing code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var wwidth = $(window).width();

    if (wwidth < 321) {
        alert("I am 320 pixels wide, or less");
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    } else if (wwidth > 321) && (wwidth < 481) {
        alert("I am between 320 and 480 pixels wide")
    }
});
```

If I remove the else if part of the code, I get the alert.  If I try to use && or || operators it will fail.  I've Googled, I can't find a reason why it's not working.  I've also tried:

```
((wwidth > 321 && wwidth < 481))
```

along with other ways, just in case it's some odd syntax thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks :)

Comment: theres a gap in your logic. what if the window is exactly 321 wide?

Comment: If that happens the world ends so it doesn't matter ;)

Comment: are you sure your window is less than 480px? Otherwise you will see no alert, even with the correct syntax (good choices for which are pointed out in the answers)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
((wwidth > 321) && (wwidth < 481))
```

This is the condition you need (http://jsfiddle.net/malet/wLrpt/).

I would also consider making your conditions clearer like so:

```
if (wwidth <= 320) {
    alert("I am 320 pixels wide, or less");
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
} else if ((wwidth > 320) && (wwidth <= 480)) {
    alert("I am between 320 and 480 pixels wide")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (wwidth > 321 && wwidth < 481) {
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. The first has already been answered, the second is "wwidth > 320" which should be "wwidth>=320". What if the window is larger than 480?

you can also implement "between" as follows:

```
Number.prototype.between = function(a, b) {
  return this >= a && this <= b
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var wwidth = $(window).width();
    if (wwidth < 321) {
      alert("I am 320 pixels wide, or less");
      window.scrollTo(0,0);
    } else if (wwidth.between(321,481))
        alert("I am between 320 and 480 pixels wide")
    else alert("I am greater than 480 pixels wide.");  
});
```

Comment: Ooh, I like 'between', I wasn't aware of that.  If the screen is larger than 480, well I have a couple of more statements that check a few more sizes, ending on a 'if it's above 1024 do this'.  It's my clunky way of changing the javascript used on the site depending upon the device.