# while && is 'and' in php, how about jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I don't want to ask this stupid question, but I have searched all over the stackoverflow and google, it seems jquery has no one ever talk about 'and' function in jquery. I use && in php, but what should I use for jquery?

Comment: You could simply just have tried if `&&` worked in jQuery, which it does.

Comment: `&&` is actually JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261150/jquery-javascript-and-the-use-of-operators

Comment: I'd suggest you read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 1):

The logical and operator in php is `&&` and `and`, they are not exactly the same though.
See [PHP : Difference between '&&' and 'AND'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511240/php-difference-between-and-and)

If you want to use the logical and operator in JavaScript (using jQuery) it is `&&`

```
if ($('#all').is(':visible') && $('#none').is(':visible')){
    // We have a problem
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_.28&&.29

Answer (score 0):

jQuery isn't a language, but a plugin for javascript.
You would use && in javascript as "and" operator just as you would do in php.

Comment: Do you have an example of some other description of the `&&` statement?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to use the `&&` logical operator in jQuery?

jQuery is a JavaScript library so you **can** use `&&`. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) from JavaScript.

If you are trying to select multiple elements I suggest you use the following:

`$("element1, element2").click(function() {...`

Answer (score 0):

MDN has an article outlining [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) in JavaScript. It states:

> **Operator:** Logical AND (`&&`)
>
> ---
>
> **Usage:** `expr1` && `expr2`
>
> ---
>
> **Description:** Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `&&` returns `true` if both operands are `true`; otherwise, returns `false`.